# My java program freezes every now and then and may have a memory leak. Is my telemetry useful?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, runnable, httpsurlconnection, telemetry

I began learning java recently (with the extra free time i have now) and wrote code for a game called torn using netbeans 8.2. This code is a runnable that continuously retrieves data from the site and stores it for later use. It was freezing mid-run, and i was told that adding a connect timeout and a read timeout for the url connection might help. I did that and it is currently running again (so far so good), and am waiting to see if that problem will happen again or not.

**My question** is about finding *memory leaks*. I read that the number of surviving generations is an indicator of whether there is a memory leak. This is a [screenshot](https://github.com/bookish303/myRepository/blob/master/run%2031%203%202020.PNG) of the telemetry after a few hours of running. [The code for the project](https://github.com/bookish303/myRepository/) is also available (OtherFactionsStats.java is the main class). (Any notes about improving my code are very welcome as well :D ). I appreciate the help.

Comment: This doesn't look like a memory leak - at least not one that is recognizable after 8 hours. Look at the top-right diagram, the blue part: the used memory oscillates between maybe 20 MB and 50 MB over the whole 8 hours. If you had a memory leak this would be a curve with a raising trend (meaning that after the 8 hour period you measured the peaks would be much clearly higher)

Comment: thats a relief. one more question..why do the surviving generations keep increasing.. thats bugging me. And thanks

Comment: They keep increasing because in your main method you create a `new RunUpdater(FactionIDpath);` every 5 seconds (`service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`) and sometimes these RunUpdaters sleep for almost an hour...

Comment: to my knowledge, the new instance is not created until the first one finishes executing.. also i compared the times in telemetry, and during sleep time the number of generations remains constant.. it actually increases much more rapidly when timeouts happen..thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I finally found your resource leak: in `LogFactionPersonalStat` on line 154 you open a file with `in = new BufferedReader(...` that never is never closed.

I suggest that you learn about [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

The code in the same file, lines 128 to 130 for example would change from

```
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("" + path + completed); //set completion status to incomplete
    file.write("0"); //zero means not yet complete
    file.close();
```

to

```
    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("" + path + completed)) { //set completion status to incomplete
        file.write("0"); //zero means not yet complete
    }
```

Not a big change, but now you cannot forget the close the `FileWriter` (or `BufferedWriter` or `BufferedReader`)

---

One other note: `RunUpdate` line 53 looks very suspicious (this pattern is repeated several times):

```
    Logger.getLogger("Error reading from file");
```

Here you create a looger for "Error reading from file", but you never use that logger to write anything into the log.

You probably meant to write something like

```
    Logger.getLogger(OtherFactionsStats.class.getName()).severe("Error: Possible timeout or problems with file");
```

or

```
    Logger.getLogger(OtherFactionsStats.class.getName()).log(Level.Severe, "Error: Possible timeout or problems with file");
```

Comment: I will look into that and see if anything changes. thank you

Comment: Hello again. solved a lot of kinks, but the project still freezes after  about 40 hours.. my new post if you feel like reading up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61053452/can-a-java-project-with-a-runnable-that-runs-at-a-fixed-rate-stop-after-a-while... thank you for all the help you gave