# Can a java project with a runnable that runs at a fixed rate stop after a while? Mine keeps freezing after about 40 hours

Tags: java, runnable, freeze, heap-dump, thread-state

After learning java on my own, i began a project for getting data from a website through api calls for a game called torn. There were a few little details i fixed thanks to some help, but the main issue i had is still not solved. after a day and a half of running, the program just freezes. i couldn't find anything about it so far. I took heap dumps for a while and i noticed some things. hope someone can help. During the first day or so, all is well (screenshot of heap dump after [3 hours](https://github.com/bookish303/FrozenJavaRunner/blob/master/after%203%20hours%20of%20running%20(during%20sleep%20timer).jpg) and after [25 hours](https://github.com/bookish303/FrozenJavaRunner/blob/master/after%2025%20hours%20of%20running%20(during%20file%20update).jpg)). Then, a few hours later, the program is still running but there is no instance of the method that runs it all ([screenshot after 30 hours](https://github.com/bookish303/FrozenJavaRunner/blob/master/after%2030%20hours%20of%20running%20(during%20file%20update).jpg)). A few hours after that the program is still running (as in it has not terminated or exited) but there is no activity and no instances of the methods at all ([40 hours into run](https://github.com/bookish303/FrozenJavaRunner/blob/master/after%2041%20hours%20of%20running%2C%202%20hours%20after%20it%20froze.jpg)).
(Some of the images may require scrolling right and left to see all the info).
I also noticed that after the program freezes, the thread for the runnable changes from "timed-waiting" to "waiting", which i also don't understand.

I have also included the [code for my project](https://github.com/bookish303/FrozenJavaRunner) (minus the actual key used in connecting to the site) along with the images in case it helps.The main is in OtherFactionsStats.java .

I appreciate all the help and advice -especially with my beginner status in java-, and thank you in advance.

Comment: does the `getFactionMembers` maybe throw an `Exception` which is not handled in your `Runnable` instance? this would cause the `ScheduledExecutorService` to stop running.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, i tried to track all exceptions to see where it might create problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if the `RunUpdater` constructor throws a RuntimeException.

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> The sequence of task executions continues indefinitely until one of the following exceptional completions occur:
>
> - The task is explicitly cancelled via the returned future.
> - The executor terminates, also resulting in task cancellation.
> - An **execution of the task throws an exception**. In this case calling get on the returned future will throw ExecutionException.
>
> Subsequent executions are suppressed. Subsequent calls to isDone() on the returned future will return true.

I would propose to replace (in `OtherFactionStats.main()`):

```
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

with

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    scheduledFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
service.shutdown();
```

This will print out any exception that occurs during `new RunUpdater()` and then gracefully shut down your application.

Comment: After solving all the problems (thanks for all your help by the way), it was still freezing.. But this time it was because i had replaced a line in my latest modification and put it inside an if-clause and it no longer ran. hopefully it is all OK now.. will be keeping an eye out just in case. :D